# Is some plugin or best practice for Gatsby to the creation of each build with a different language?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Let's assume that I have already created a website in Gatsby with English texts on www.someWebsiteUrl.**com**. Now I need the same page but with Spanish texts on site www.someWebsiteUrl.**es**. 
Is any way how to define which site with specific translations should be created?

Something like: `gatsby build en` or `gatsby build es`

In other words, I need a multi-language site with a different build for each domain with different TLD.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/localization-i18n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, you decide how and where to deploy your site.

A possible solution might be adding an environment variable and trigger it within your deployment:

```
// Configure the environment variable within your deploy options
LANGUAGE=eng
```

```
// Use it within your app to generate the specific content
process.env.LANGUAGE
```

For example, check how to use [environment variables with Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#declare-variables), and [within gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/).